# Cast from double to size_t yields wrong result?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++20

The following code works.
My question is, should 2) not lead to a result very close to 1) ?
Why is 2) casted to such a small amount ?
Whereby, maybe worth to note 2) is exactly half of 1):

```
std::cout << "1)  " << std::pow(2, 8 * sizeof(size_t)) << std::endl;
std::cout << "2)  " << static_cast<size_t>(std::pow(2, 8 * sizeof(size_t))) << std::endl;
```

The output is:

1. 18446744073709551616
2. 9223372036854775808

Comment: Unrelated: don't use `pow` for this. Use bit shifting: `1<< 8 * sizeof(size_t)`. On second thought, don't use this either. 2 to the 64 will overflow `size_t` no matter how you compute it.

Comment: Which compiler and version do you use?

Comment: @t.niese Visual Studio 2019 (v142), /std:c++latest

Comment: It's not *odd* - it's *even* . But MSVC (VS2019) gives the same output; clang-cl gives `0`.

Comment: `std::pow()` is going to return a double that can hold the value correctly. But this value is to large to hold in a `size_t` (you shifted 1 bit to far) so the result is undefined and when you print it out you are getting some random value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is due to that part of the specification:

> **7.3.10 Floating-integral conversions** [conv.fpint]
>
> A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.**

The value `18446744073709551616` (that's the truncated part) is larger than `std::numberic_limit<size_t>::max()` on your system, and due to that, the behavior of that cast is undefined.

Comment: Yep! Giving an answer *exactly* half that expected counts as part of "undefined behaviour!"

Comment: @t.niese Regarding your 7.3.10. But there is no truncated value since 2 to the 64 has no fractional part.

Comment: The truncation is unimportant for this case. The number is too large whether a fractional portion was lopped off or not.

Comment: @user4581301 2 to 64 is std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() + 1 but because of modulo the largest +1 it should come to 0 hence is not too large if thedatatype is unsigned long long. But double could hold a much bigger value.

Comment: @t.niese 2 to 64 is std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() + 1 but because of modulo the largest +1 it should come to 0 if the datatype is unsigned long long. And double could hold a much bigger value.

Comment: @ByronB The size test comes before the modulo. 2 to the 64 is too big for `size_t` and all bets are off after that, but I would have expected the UB to do the modulo thing because it's easy and given you 0. Clearly that's not what you got, though.

Comment: @ByronB you do a `static_cast<size_t>` on  the double `18446744073709551616` and in your original answer you wrote `18446744073709551615 is std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`, and the double `18446744073709551616` is larger than `18446744073709551615`.

Comment: @t.niese but static_cast<size_t>(std::pow(2, 8 * sizeof(size_t))-1.0) yields also 9223372036854775808. And ...-2.0 yields also to that very same result

Comment: `std::pow(2, 8 * sizeof(size_t))` is so large that likely a `double` cannot resolve the -1.

Comment: @user4581301 yes I do agree with that.

Comment: @ByronB `std::pow(2, 8 * sizeof(size_t))-1.0` also results in `18446744073709551616` so the problem is the same.

Comment: If I remember my encoding correctly, you'll have to subtract 1025 before you'll see it, and then it'll jump significantly, 2K I think. Mind you the encoding can vary so I'm likely dead wrong on  a lot of platforms.

Comment: @t.niese and user4581301 I really want to thank you very much for your ambitious help so far. Maybe you still consider this: If I write my own power funtion:                                                                                 
unsigned long long powerInt(unsigned long long base, unsigned long long exponent) {

 unsigned long long result = 1;
 for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <= exponent; ++i)
  result *= base;

 return result;
} then static_cast<size_t>(powerInt(2, 64)) gives me 0. I am not surewhat that shows in our discussion...

Comment: @user4581301 Not sure if I use  `std::nexttoward` correctly, but if I do and interpret it correctly the next smaller interpretable value would be `18446744073709549568` according to  `std::nexttoward(std::pow(2, 8 * sizeof(size_t)), 0.0)`, so `2048` smaller. But yes subtracting `1025` would also yield to that.

Comment: @ByronB your `powerInt` does an integer multiplication for which the result exceeds the limit of `unsigned long long` the `static_cast` isn't relevant there as the problem already occurs in the `powerInt` itself.  What will happen there is a different question to what you have asked. Please don't start a discussion about new problems in the comment section.

Comment: @t.niese sorry for the deviation. And yes the modulo the largest + 1 happens inside powerInt  already and so it returns already 0, understood now.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to calculate the amount of different values a certain unsigned integral datatype
can represent we can calculate

```
 std::cout << "1)  " << std::pow(2, 8 * sizeof(size_t)) << std::endl; // yields 18446744073709551616
```

This calculates 2 to the power of 64 and yields 18446744073709551616.
Since sizeof(size_t) is 8 byte, on a 64 bit machine,
and a byte has 8 bit, the width of the size_t data type is 64 bit hence 2^64.

This is no surprise since usually it is the case that size_t on a system has the width of its
underlying hardware bus system since we want to consume no more than one clock cycle to deliver
an address or an index of an array or vector.

The above number represents the amount of all different integral values that can be
represented by an unsigned integral datatype of 64 bit like size_t or unsigned long long
including 0 as one possibility.
And since it does include 0, the highest value to be represented is exactly one less,
so 18446744073709551615.

This number can also be retrieved by

```
 std::cout << std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() << std::endl; // yields 18446744073709551615
 std::cout << std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() << std::endl; // yields the same
```

Now an unsigned datatype stores its values like

```
   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 is 0 
   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 is 1 or 2^0
   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010 is 2 or 2^1
   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011 is 3 or 2^1+2^0
   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100 is 4 or 2^2
   ...
   11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 is 18446744073709551615
   and if you want to add another 1, you would need a 65th bit on the left which you dont have:
 1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 is 0 because 
   there are no more bits on the left.
```

Any amount higher than the highest possible value you would wish to represent
will come down to amount modulo the largest possible value + 1. (amount % (max + 1))
which leads as we can see to zero in above sample.

And since this comes so naturally the standard defines that if you convert any
integral datatype signed or unsigned to another unsigned integral datatype it is to be converted
amount modulo the largest possible value + 1. Beautiful.

But this easy rule has a little surprise for us when we wish to convert a negative integral to an
unsigned integral like -1 to unsigned long long for eaxample. You have a 0 value first and then
you deduct 1. What happens is the oposite sequence of the above sample. Have a look:

```
  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 is 0 and now do -1
  11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 is 18446744073709551615
```

So yes, converting -1 to size_t leads to std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max(). Quite unbelievable
at first but understandable after some thinking and playing around with it.

Now for our second line of code

```
 std::cout << "2)  " << static_cast<size_t>(std::pow(2, 8 * sizeof(size_t))) << std::endl;
```

we would expect naively 18446744073709551616, the same result as line one, of course.

But since we know now about modulo the largest + 1 and we know now that the largest plus one
gives 0 we would also, again naively, accept 0 as an answer.

Why naively? Because std::pow returns a double and not an integral datatype.
The double datatype is again 64 bit but internally its representation is entirely different.

```
 0XXXXXXX XXXX0000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Only those 11 X bits represent the exponent in 2^n form. That means only those 11 bits have to show 64
and the double will represent 2^64 * 1. So the representation of our big number is much more compact
in double than in size_t. Would someone want to do modulo the largest plus 1 some more conversion would be
needed before to change the representation of 2^64 into a 64 bit line.

Some further reading about floating point representation can be found at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/ieee-floating-point-representation?view=msvc-160
for example.

And the standard says that if you convert a floating value
to an integral which cannot be represented by the target integral datatype the result is UB, undefined behaviour.

See the C++17 Standard ISO/IEC14882:
7.10 Floating-integral conversions [conv.fpint]

1. A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates ;
   that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented
   in the destination type. ...

So double can easily hold 2^64 and thats the reason why line 1 could print out so easily. But it is 1
too much to be represented in size_t so the result is UB.
So whatever is the outcome of our line 2 is simply irrelevant because it is UB.

Ok, but if any random result will do, how come the UB outcome is exactly half?
Well fist of all, the outcome is from MSVC. Clang or other compiler may deliver any other UB result.

But lets look at the "half" outcome since it is easy.

```
   Trying to add 1 to the largest  
   11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 is 18446744073709551615
   would if only integrals would be involved lead to, 
 1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
   but thats not possible since the bit does not exist and it is not integral but double datatype and 
   hence UB, so accidentially the result is
   10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 which is 9223372036854775808
   so exactly half of the naively expected or 2^63.
```